# Random Number Guessing Game - Limit the Number of guesses

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a program that generates a random number which the user guesses. It also limits the number of guesses the user can make (or is supposed to.)

```
     var highLimit = 5;
        var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * highLimit) + 1);
        var allowedGuesses = 2;
        var numGuesses = 0;

        function guessingGame() {
            if (numGuesses <= allowedGuesses) {                    

               do {
                    inputNum = document.numForm.number.value;
                    inputNum = parseInt(inputNum);


                    if (inputNum < randNum && inputNum > 1) {
                        document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Sorry, your guess was too low.";
                        numGuesses++;
                    }

                    else if (inputNum > randNum && inputNum < highLimit) {
                        document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Sorry, your guess was too high.";
                        numGuesses++;
                    }
                    else if (inputNum == randNum) {
                        document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Congratulations! You guessed correctly.";
                        numGuesses++;
                    }

                    else {
                        document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Your guess was out of the desired parameters. Please guess again.";
                        numGuesses--;
                    }

                } while(numGuesses < allowedGuesses && inputNum != randNum);

            }

                else {
                    document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Sorry, you have reached the allowed number of guesses, which is " + allowedGuesses + "." + " Click 'New Game' to try again.";
                }
            return false;
        }

        numGuesses = 0;
        function newGame() {
                randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * highLimit) + 1);
                guessingGame();
                return false;
           }
```

And the HTML:

```
 <form name = "numForm">
        <fieldset>
            <label for = "randNum">Enter a number between 1 and 5: </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "number" value = "" id = "randNum" size = "1" maxlength = "1" />
        </fieldset>
        <input class = "button" type = "button" name = "submit" onclick = "guessingGame()" value = "Submit Number"  />

        <input class = "button" type = "reset" name = "newGame" onclick = "newGame()" value = "New Game" />
        <fieldset>
            <textarea name = "gameResults"  onclick = "" readonly = "true" value = "" rows = "5" cols = "40" ></textarea>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Right now, the program is stuck in a infinite loop since highLimit is set at 5. But if I set it at ten, the program works. How can I fix it so it works at any value? I would also appreciate other suggestions for improvement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not see how this approach can work.  The `while` loop will just check the same value in `document.numForm.number.value` over and over without giving the user a chance to enter another value.  You need to get rid of the loop and increment `numGuesses` once per button click.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a loop in this one. You can simple say:

```
function guessingGame() {
    if (numGuesses < 0){numGuesses=0;}
    if ((numGuesses < allowedGuesses) && (inputNum != randNum)) {                    
            inputNum = document.numForm.number.value;
            inputNum = parseInt(inputNum);


            if (inputNum < randNum && inputNum > 1) {
                document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Sorry, your guess was too low.";
                numGuesses++;
            }

            else if (inputNum > randNum && inputNum < highLimit) {
                document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Sorry, your guess was too high.";
                numGuesses++;
            }
            else if (inputNum == randNum) {
                document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Congratulations! You guessed correctly.";
                numGuesses++;
            }

            else {
                document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Your guess was out of the desired parameters. Please guess again.";
                numGuesses--;
            }
    }

        else {
            document.numForm.gameResults.value = "Sorry, you have reached the allowed number of guesses, which is " + allowedGuesses + "." + " Click 'New Game' to try again.";
        }
    return false;
}
```

the `if (numGuesses < 0){numGuesses=0;}` will help also. for negative cases.

Comment: How can I alter the program so I would have to use a loop to allow multiple attempts?

Answer (score 0):

**This is an update for:**

> Ran the Snippet and answeared in "0 tries"

This is how I did it: But you're going to have to replace the 'prompts' and  'alerts' with your specified inputs and outputs, if you still need it after  4 years:

```js
 let maximum = parseInt(prompt('Enter the maximum number!') );
    while(!maximum) {
      maximum = parseInt (prompt('Please enter a valid number') )
    }
    const targetNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*maximum)+1;
    let attempts =0;
    let maxAttempts = Math.ceil(maximum/2);

    // ==== Uncomment the line below to cheat --> ======

    // console.log(targetNum)

    let guess = parseInt(prompt(`Enter your first guess!, you have ${maxAttempts} attempts (press 'q' anytime to escape from this hellish nightmare)`));
    while(parseInt(guess) !==targetNum && attempts < maxAttempts-1)  {
     
      if (typeof(guess) === 'string' && guess.toLowerCase() ==='q') {break;}
      attempts++;
      if(guess>targetNum) {
        guess = (prompt(`Too High! Enter new guess! attempts left: ${maxAttempts- attempts} (press 'q' anytime to escape from this hellish nightmare)`))
      }else {
        guess= (prompt(`Too low! Entere a new Guess! attempts left: ${maxAttempts- attempts} (press 'q' anytime to escape from this hellish nightmare)`))
      }
    } 
    if(typeof(guess) === 'string' && guess.toLowerCase() ==='q') {
      alert(`You gave up after ${attempts} attempts`); 
    }
    else if(attempts >= maxAttempts-1) {alert(`Oops, your ${maxAttempts} attempts ran out, the number was ${targetNum}: Verification : ${targetNum==guess}`);}
    else {
    alert(`Good job, you got it ${attempts+1} attempts!, the number was ${targetNum}: Verification : ${targetNum==guess}`) ; 
    }
```

Comment: Heh - I just ran your snippet and I found that I guessed the correct solution in ***0*** attempts! Maybe a very minor modification is required?

Comment: I got it going now i think @AdrianMole